# import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/361

Tags: python, x-server

I am trying to run a python script to generate heatmap and clustering dendrogram. But I got an error message saying :

`import: unable to open X server @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/361`

I am a new to both linux and python. So I cannot make out utterly why the error happened. Dose anyone know how to solve this problem?

My OS is linux fedora.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more ? Python version, which part of your code generates that error ? etc...

Answer (score 6):

Your script is being interpreted by a shell instead of python.  The shell attempts to execute the X `import` command and that external `/usr/bin/export` command prints the error.

Make sure you have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top of each python executable script (not necessary for imported libraries).  This causes the script to be interpreted by python.